# Image upload to Parse Server using Angular and Ionic not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I have been unable tu upload an image to Parse Server using Angular and Ionic on a hybrid mobile app. I am using the latest version of Parse Sever and the Parse Javascript SDK. I am always getting the error 130: Invalid file upload.

I believe I have to encode the image to base 64, am I correct?
This is my upload code:

```
    $scope.doSignUp = function(){
        // if (true) 
        // {
        //  $scope.image_error = "* Por favor selecciona una imagen";
        //}else{
            var file = "";
            window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile($scope.collection.selectedImage, function(base64){
                file = base64;
            });
            var imageFile = new Parse.File("image.png",  { base64: file },"image/png");
            imageFile.save().then(function() {
                var user = new Parse.User();
                user.set("username", $scope.user.username);
                user.set("password", $scope.user.password);
                user.set("email", $scope.user.email);
                user.set("picture", imageFile);//getting file need url
                user.signUp(null, {
                    success: function(user) {
                        $state.go('app.home');
                    },
                    error: function(user, error) {
                // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.dir(error);
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            });

        //$state.go('app.feeds-categories');
    //}
};
```

Comment: If you encode and send a large image like 1mb, I think express server via body parsing module throws an error like entity too large. Dont know in case of parse server. Give it a try

Comment: @NidhinDavid Could be, let my try to encode a very small image to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Did you try that?

```
var user = new Parse.User();
var base64 = "V29ya2luZyBhdCBQYXJzZSBpcyBncmVhdCE=";
var imageFile = new Parse.File("image.png", { base64: base64 });

user.set("username", $scope.user.username);
user.set("password", $scope.user.password);
user.set("email", $scope.user.email);
user.set("picture", imageFile);//getting file need url

user.signUp(null, {
    success: function (user) {
        $state.go('app.home');
    },
    error: function (user, error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```